# PHP capitalize unicode string in brackets

Tags: php

I want to capitalize every word even if it is in any kind of brackets () <> [] {}. It should capitalize unicode chars aswell.

For example:

```
ti si želva (čestitke)
```

should produce

```
Ti Si Želva (Čestitke)
```

I was using this function for very long time

```
function ucwords2($str)
{
    $str = strtolower($str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(?<![a-z]\')\b[a-z]/e', 'strtoupper(\'$0\')', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

but now i need unicode support so it became unusable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

```
$txt='ti si želva (čestitke)';
echo mb_convert_case($txt,MB_CASE_TITLE,'utf-8');
```

Got it?

Comment: Nice answer. As a general rule, switching to Unicode implies saving files as UTF-8, using the mb_* equivalents of string functions and adding the `u` flag to regular expressions.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. But is one problem. It also capitalizes letters behind ' or ". So "it's" becomes "It'S"

Comment: Is there any solution with mb_ereg_replace ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the isLower() function is unicode-aware, so I think this would be a better way to check the characters. Don't know how you can do this into your regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function to_up($txt){
    $up=mb_convert_case($txt,MB_CASE_TITLE,'utf-8');
    return strtr($up,
        array(
            "'S"=>"'s",
            "'D"=>"'d",
            "'L"=>"'l"
        )
    );
}

$txt="john, it's all your fault!";
echo to_up($txt);
```

Note that you can add anything you want in the array...